# Case-Insensitive String Comparison in Slick?

Tags: scala, orm, slick

What is the proper way of finding the one User matching username?

With user-defined type User:

```
case class User (userId: String, username: String)

object User extends Table[User]("user") {
  def userId = column[String]("userId", O.PrimaryKey)
  def username = column[String]("username")
  def * = userId ~ authId ~ username <>(User.apply _, User.unapply _)

  Database.forDataSource(DB.getDataSource()) withSession {
    implicit session: Session =>

    val q = for { u <- User if u.username.equalsIgnoreCase(someUsername) }
      yield u
    q.headOption
```

user.username is of type Column[String] which has no conversion to String.

What is desired is to have the Database do the string-insensitive comparison as part of the query.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had a similar situation and solved it by using `toLowerCase` extension method:

`p <- u.party if p.loginName.toLowerCase === partyName.toLowerCase`

You can find [here](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick/src/main/scala/slick/lifted/ExtensionMethods.scala) more extension methods, especially [String ones](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick/src/main/scala/slick/lifted/ExtensionMethods.scala#L110).

Comment: Interestingly, I was trying to do something similar and equalise strings using the `.capitalize` method under Slick, however that didn't work as it only capitalised my `partyName` string, not the `p.loginName` one. `.toLowerCase` seems to do the trick though!

Comment: You should note that for large tables this becomes very inefficient and in some cases it might prevent the proper use of indexes. I remember one particular case where this was the most frequent run query, the whole thing was having a dramatic impact on the whole system. Some DB systems might allow the creation of indexes on function applications (eg:LOWERCASE(`loginName`)) but in this particular case I had to create a secondary column in the db `loginName_lowercase` which held a lowercase copy of the `loginName` and which was used in the query. This had a very positive impact on performance.